# Error Locating Server/Instance Specified using SQLNCLI10.1

Tags: vbscript, sql-server-2008-r2, port, connection-string, firewall

following scenario with a firewall inbetween this PCs:

1. Client PC

   - IP 10.10.140.100
   - Subnet 255.255.0.0
   - Gateway: 10.10.0.254
2. Server PC

   - IP 10.40.140.100
   - Subnet 255.255.0.0
   - Gateway: 10.140.255.254

The communication itself is already working (ping, using a WebClient) so don't worry too much about that. 
I'm facing a connection problem connecting to a named instance (in this case "WINCC") from the Client PC to the Server PC(SQL Server 2008 R2) using the following connection string in the application (Database name is correct, have checked that!):

```
    strserver = "10.40.140.100"
    strConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;    Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=" & Database & ";Data Source=" & strServer & "\WINCC"
```

Circumstances:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client is installed on the Client PC
- The windows user used on the Client PC is existing on the Server PC and part of the necessary User Group (in this case SIMATIC HMI Group because of WinCC)
- I have looked up the dynamic port used by the sql server which is 49181 and the port was opened in the firewall of the network
- This has worked in every other network environment till now but something is still somehow blocking the access in the network

The script is crashing with the following error:
"SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]" when attempting to establish the connection to the database (.Open command).
I'm 99% sure it has to do something with a port not opened. I have seen several times that the UDP Port 1434 of the Sql Browser service has to be open for  . Is this also relevant when using the SQL NAtive Client Provider? Or should I try to name the port specifically in the connection string? (Like "10.40.140.100,49181/WINCC"?)

Any comment is appreciated, thanks!
Best regards, 
CMSPaul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Dynamic port can often cause issues.  If you have an App server connecting to the SQL server inside your network I would suggest using a Static IP on the SQL server and then route it through the firewall as defined.  Also as you said I would define the TCP/IP port in your connection string.

This would be set up in SQL Server Configuration manager under SQL Server Network Configuration.  Select Protocols for .  Right click TCP/IP and select the IP Address tab.  Make sure all TCP Dynamic Ports are set to 0.  Under IPALL, set the TCP Port to the static IP address.  Once that is done, you will need to restart the SQL server service.

Comment: I have thought about this solution too and I will try this way the week after next. Thanks for your confirmation though, I will tell you how it goes!

Comment: I think it should fit what you need.  Good luck!!

Comment: In the end the problem was that the SQl server was set up with IPv6 address when installed and when trying to connect from the client to the server he could not link the IPv4 address to the correct SQL server. But nevertheless a static IP is now used for the SQL server just to be save.
Thanks again for your help!